# UIActivityViewController Email Sharing

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController in my project for sharing in iOS 6.0. It shows the `Email Option`. 
But when there is `No Email Account`, it `does not take me to the settings page` to setup my account but rather does nothing and returns NO in the "completed" boolean flag. Any ideas `how to go to the settings page` or any workaround for this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it for Twitter, you'll have to make the appropriate changes to use it for Mail:

```
    if (![TwitterSettings hasAccounts]) {

        //NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
        [TwitterSettings openTwitterAccounts];
    }

//
//  TwitterSettings.m
//
//

#import "TwitterSettings.h"

@implementation TwitterSettings

+ (BOOL)hasAccounts {
    // For clarity
    return [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
}

+ (void)openTwitterAccounts {

    SLComposeViewController *ctrl = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    if ([ctrl respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) {
        // Manually invoke the alert view button handler
        [(id <UIAlertViewDelegate>)ctrl alertView:nil
                             clickedButtonAtIndex:kTwitterSettingsButtonIndex];
    }
  //  [ctrl release];
}



@end
```